# Tables having words and phrases entry

Tags: tables

This question might be silly, it's easy to look at and could've been answered after looking at the Internet, but still, I came here for 
help. This question look like this:

I want to create a table using LaTeX. The table looks like this:

[image: (LOGINtest.png)]

I was able to manage make a table, but it is not what I envisioned. It looks like this:

[image: (LOGINtest.png)]

The code I used looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{USERNAME} & \multirow{2}{*}{PASSWORD} & Did the user denied access to the app when the user inputted wrong username or password? \\

                         &                          &  YES                    & NO \\
                    \hline
papad@gmail.com          & 7221456                  &                         & \\ 
                     \hline
idislikeyou@gmail.com    & password                 &                         &  \\
                     \hline
devs@gmail.com           & 12A2ZAQR                 &                         & \\
                     \hline
devs@gmail.com           & password                 &                         & \\
                     \hline

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

My question is:

> How can we make a table using LaTeX that looks like the first picture above?

And I wonder what is the best book for LaTeX to be read...

Comment: Should this table fit in a single column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this enough?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}*{2}{c}*{2}{C{.5\linewidth}}@{}}
        \toprule
        \multirow{2}{*}{USERNAME} & \multirow{2}{*}{PASSWORD} & \multicolumn{2}{C{\linewidth}}{Did the user denied access to the app when the user inputted wrong username or password?} \\ \cmidrule{3-4}
                                  &                           &    YES     &                                                      NO                                                       \\ \midrule
             papad@gmail.com      &          7221456          & \checkmark &                                                                                                               \\ 
          idislikeyou@gmail.com   &         password          & \checkmark &                                                  \checkmark                                                   \\ 
             devs@gmail.com       &         12A2ZAQR          & \checkmark &                                                                                                               \\ 
             devs@gmail.com       &         password          &            &                                                  \checkmark                                                   \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Edit

Code revision to fit the needs

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{*{2}{|c}*{2}{|C{.5\linewidth}}|}
            \hline
            \multirow{3}{*}{USERNAME} & \multirow{3}{*}{PASSWORD} & \multicolumn{2}{C{\linewidth}|}{Did the user denied access to the app when the user inputted wrong username or password?} \\ \cline{3-4}
            &                           &    YES     &                                                      NO                                                       \\ \hline
            papad@gmail.com      &          7221456          & \checkmark &                                                                                                               \\ \hline
            idislikeyou@gmail.com   &         password          & \checkmark &                                                  \checkmark                                                   \\ \hline
            devs@gmail.com       &         12A2ZAQR          & \checkmark &                                                                                                               \\ \hline
            devs@gmail.com       &         password          &            &                                                  \checkmark                                                   \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Almost there....But I like that the LaTeX version is almost the same as the first picture above...hehehehee

Comment: For sure it's possible to reproduce your table (remember, it's about LaTeX here ;) ). However, I recommend to have a look at  [Mori's paper](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2007-1/mori/mori.pdf) and [booktabs documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) in order to help you design good tables.

Comment: hey...uhmmm how do you put a caption on the table above?